# Not able to get internet connection from my Ethernet

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, internet, ethernet

Hello Ubuntu community!

So few weeks ago I installed ubuntu 16.04 alongside with my w10. Everything worked as supposed at the begining, I'm already familiar with ubuntu and its installing.

Anyway, I found later that my USB 3.0 didn't work in ubuntu, neither my usb powered keyboard and mouse.

I found online a workaround by enabling some options in my motherboard, and that did the trick, but i'm stuck with my ethernet problem.

Apparently ethernet connection is not working, and I have tried everything.

I don't really know what else to do, and I need my ubuntu runing ASAP, as I need it for class.

As I knew you guys would need some info, I already got some.
lshw -c network

```
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 10
   serial: 40:8d:5c:b4:d4:85
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:40 memory:fe200000-fe23ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

ifconfig

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:8d:5c:b4:d4:85  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1692 (1.6 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:144904 (144.9 KB)  TX bytes:144904 (144.9 KB)
```

network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet dhcp
```

Other info

Processor
AMD FX Series FX-8350 4.0Ghz 8X Black Edition

Motherboard
Gigabyte GA-970-Gaming

If somebody could help me it would be awesome, these problems are very anoying...

Thank you! If you need more info, just let me know!
Sorry for bad english :P

Comment: Ethernet not getting an IP address could be one of any number of issues, but the fact that it's detected already (it seems) makes me think it's a different issue than drivers.  You said you did something to make the USB work, did the Ethernet work before that?  Do you use Network Manager (the GUI) to manage the Ethernet?

Comment: @ThomasWard Nope. For some reason, last time I installed ubuntu (was 14.04), it authomatically connected to the ethernet after I tried to sudo apt-get update. I didn't change anything and at the next day, I couldn't connect.